# Let taskbar thumbnails diappear when you move mouse out

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

When I move the mouse over the Windows 10 taskbar, thubmnail preview appears. But when I move the mouse out, they just stay there!

[image]

This is really annoying. Is this normal behaviour? Do you experience it too? How to make them disappear simply when I move the mouse out?

After longer time experimenting I found that pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will make it disappear, but I want to make it disappear automatically - this should be the proper behaviour with hover thumbnails!