# Winows 10 taskbar preivew disappear

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, preview

My goal is really quite simple. I want to make it such that there is no delay between my mouse moving away from the window preview (from the taskbar) and that preview disappearing.

Somehow, in the year of our lord 2022, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. I was able to get rid of the delay in the appearance of the preview with the `ExtendedUIHoverTime` registry value, but that's all I've got so far.

I found questions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1563436/let-taskbar-thumbnails-diappear-when-you-move-mouse-out) from people with the same problem, but no answers. Someone please tell me I've just missed something obvious.

Comment: Yea it's prob ~750-1000 ms, but that's **entirely** too long. I want an instant response. Especially when I'm working, I want stuff to snap.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAA WHY? Why would MS not let the user control that? I genuinely don't understand. Also does that mean there is some hacky work-around?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible to do this to the windows taskbar. But... There are taskbar replacements that can do it.

I myself use ActualTools Window Manager, which has a feature to customize the taskbar and replace it with its own variant, and this one actually allows you to set it to 0 ms. It is not instant, but the delay is so small, I'm sure you'll think this is acceptable.

You can disable the fade effect, but then it is actually less snappy. The 0.2ms delay before the preview closes is more noticable and is probably more annoying, but it will appear very snappy otherwise, so that is a matter of preference.

The only downside... ActualTools Window Manager is not free but it can do so much, its definitely worth the money, and once the license expires, you can just keep using that version, so essentially its a pay once thingy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The fact this is both paid and proprietary makes my teeth itch, but at least it's an option.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt you can find a taskbar replacement that is free, but you may find one that is cheaper.

Comment: Also, The Window manager is the total suite. You can actually go for ActualTools Multiple Monitors only, that is the part that has the multi-monitor taskbar replacement. Its cheaper.